# Evaluate the following

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I imagine that this will not provde a significant challenge for many people, but I can't quite get my head around it. It doesn't help that I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking for.

If $x + \frac {1}x = 8$ , evaluate $x^4 + \frac {1}{x^4}$

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I apologise if the tag is not appropriate, but I was having trouble finding a suitable one.

Comment: similar: http://www.edugoog.com/details/196-194-192-190-if-x-1-x-4-then-x-4-1-x-4-is-equal-to-basic-operation-factorization.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^4+\frac 1{x^4}=(x^2+\frac 1{x^2})^2-2=((x+\frac 1x)^2-2)^2-2$

Now put the value.

Answer (score 1):

$$x+\frac 1x=8 \iff x^2 + 1 = 8x\ \wedge\ x \ne 0$$

Does that help?

Comment: Squaring is better...

Comment: I guess so.  This isn't exactly hard though.